# How to register entity in XML::LibXML for parsing?

Tags: perl, xml-libxml

Loading XML document with unknown entity results in error:

```
$ perl -MXML::LibXML -lE 'XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => "<doc>&nbsp;</doc>");'
:1: parser error : Entity 'nbsp' not defined
<doc>&nbsp;</doc>
           ^
```

How to make XML::LibXML parse that XML document and recognize `&nbsp;` and replace it with Unicode non-breaking-space character?

Comment: I'm not sure how to influence XML::LibXML in this way, but Mojo::DOM in XML mode works: `perl -MMojo::DOM -lE 'say Mojo::DOM->new->xml(1)->parse("<doc>&nbsp;</doc>")->to_string'`

Comment: @Grinnz, ouch! That's so buggy! An XML schema is allowed to define `&nbsp;` however its want.

Comment: Of course, but the likelihood of that actually mattering approaches zero.

Comment: @Grinnz, Why would you think that next to nothing uses different entities than XHTML? (Or were you pretending the bug is just about `&nbsp;`?)

Answer (score 3):

`&nbsp;` is not a [builtin/predefined XML entity](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-predefined-ent). It thus needs to be defined by the particular schema of the XML document.

For example, if you are parsing XHTML, you should have one of the following at the top to define all XHTML entities:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

or

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

If the DTD for your schema doesn't define `&nbsp;`, you can use an actual non-breaking space or `&#xA0;`.

---

Note that using the above DOCTYPE means that parsing the document requires XML::LibXML to fetch `xhtml1-strict.dtd` or `xhtml11.dtd` every time you parse such a document that mentions them in this manner, which is a waste of resources. Adding the following to your program avoids that:

```
use XML::Catalogs::HTML -libxml;
```

Note that the following `DOCTYPE` directives are sufficient when using XML::Catalogs::HTML:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN">
```

or

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN">
```

---

Pro tip: Provide the `no_network` option to the XML::LibXML parser to ensure that it doesn't accidentally fetch DTDs from the internet. This doesn't prevent XML::Catalogs::HTML from working, so it's a great combination!

Comment: This answer assumes that the whole document is xhtml, which isn't in my case. We are getting xml documents (without namespaces) and inside some of the elements, there are xhtml snippets with html entities that breaks the XML::LibXML parsing.

Answer (score 1):

[XML includes only a few entities.](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-predefined-ent) You need to add a DTD that includes the entity. Untested:

```
<!DOCTYPE just_make_it_work [
    <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
]>
<doc>&nbsp;</doc>
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<doc>&nbsp;</doc>
```

Comment: This (doctype + entity markup) works, but it means that the original xml has to be edited before parsing? Is there any way to assign DTD or doctype to a document before parsing it in XML::LibXML?